# Proper way to end continuous Python process

Tags: multithreading, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

What is proper practice for stopping a continuously running Python process? Consider the following code:

```py
from multiprocessing import Process

run_process = Process(target=self.run)

def start_running():
    run_process.start()

def run():
    while True:
        # Do stuff

def stop_running():
    # ???
    run_process.join()
```

I would expect that the ideal situation would be to have the run() process end on its own when stop_running() is called. One idea is to signal a semaphore in stop_running(), which is checked in the run() loop, so it knows to break. But I would like to know what common practice is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no "proper" way of doing much of anything in Python. As you are running a process instead of a thread, you have more options, which is good.

If your process does not have a risk of being stuck completely and it does not have the risk of being stuck on IO waiting for input potentially indefinitely (for example from a queue), I would use a semaphore or a variable to signal the process it should exit now.

If there is a risk of the process being stuck in wait, you can get rid of it by `run_process.kill()` or `run_process.terminate()`. Kill equals kill -9 in shell and is guaranteed to get the job done.

The drawback in killing/terminating a process is that if the process holds any shared objects (queues, shared variables etc), those become corrupted also in the other processes that share them. It is safe to discard them but if you keep reading from them, you may encounter occasionally obscure exceptions that are hard to debug.

So as always it depends. The variable/semaphore method has its strengths but if there is a risk of the subprocess being stuck in sleep or wait and not checking the condition, you do not achieve anything.  If your subprocess does not share any resources with other processes, kill may be simpler and a guaranteed way of getting rid of your process.